# Forecast combination approaches or: How to beat the simple average?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, predictive-models

Say, i have a set of two forecasters (or 'experts'), who provide a forecast for wind power time series and i have to pick the best expert (or a somehow-weighted combination of both experts) to have an overall better forecast. 
Here, i can do a simple uniformly weighted average, which often beats many other forecast combination methods. [(Diebold 2017, p.405ff)](http://www.ssc.upenn.edu/~fdiebold/Teaching221/Forecasting.pdf)

Other elaborated approaches were suggested in the literature, most prominently variance-covariance based methods originally developed by [Bates & Cranger,1969](ftp://rammftp.cira.colostate.edu/Knaff/Annular_pres/3008764.pdf). Especially in the field of ensemble learning, there are algorithms to robustly combine experts ([Littestone & Warmuth, 1994](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540184710091)). Further developments of picking the best expert advise based on its prior performance via  exponentially weighted aggregation ([see Cesa-Bianchi & Lugosi 2006, p.7ff](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiVov3rys3ZAhUPLewKHTuKBZ4QFggqMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ii.uni.wroc.pl%2F~lukstafi%2Fpmwiki%2Fuploads%2FAGT%2FPrediction_Learning_and_Games.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1K1qwy_3j54F9PNaFqfcSa)) also exist. Especially the last method is often used in online machine learning literature, where it is opposed to batch learning alghorithms to overcome computational limitations. [(if you are interested: Opera Package which implements the online learning in R)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/opera/index.html)

**Now to my problem**: Recently, i have gained the opportunity (for my master thesis) to access an additional set of 7 weather experts who provide **meterological** forecast data like wind speed, direction, temperature and air pressure. My previous mentioned set of 2 experts who provide **wind power** forecasts also rely on meteorological experts and probably they use the same weather data as an input for their predictions, but i am not sure and i don't have insight to their models. They are black boxes to me.

In my understanding i have a univariate regression problem, because i want to predict a future value based on a different set of experts; 
in the next step I would like to create a model which uses the wind power predictions of my 2 wind power experts and additionaly considers the meteorological data of 7 weather experts.

I have read a lot of literature (mostly journal articles) on that combination topic but cannot yet decide how to combine my initial 2 forecasts with additional meteorological data. Obviously as a first step because of different units, i need to standardize, which is a topic on its own - still straightforward. But the next steps are a bit confusing, because i have so many approaches to build my regression model, especially considered in the broad field of statistics.

In the field of computer science, Recurrent Neural networks - especially Long Short Term Memory for time series forecasting - seems to be a promising research avenue nowadays. I have to deep dive further in that topic to assess whether they fit to my problem or not.

Any recommendation for suitable methods is highly appreciated!